# (phusion passenger:?) How to switch off httpd/error_log message "Either the vistor clicked on the 'Stop' button ..."

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, phusion-passenger

Our httpd/error_log is flooded with messages like

`[ pid=9705 thr=140631357052896 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:784 time=2014-09-13 10:18:10.379 ]: Either the vistor clicked on the 'Stop' button in the web browser, or the visitor's connection has stalled and couldn't receive the data that Apache is sending to it. As a result, you will probably see a 'Broken Pipe' error in this log file. Please ignore it, this is normal. You might also want to increase Apache's TimeOut configuration option if you experience this problem often.
    [ pid=9775 thr=140631357052896 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:784 time=2014-09-13 10:25:38.763 ]: Either the vistor clicked on the 'Stop' button in the web browser, or the visitor's connection has stalled and couldn't receive the data that Apache is sending to it. As a result, you will probably see a 'Broken Pipe' error in this log file. Please ignore it, this is normal. You might also want to increase Apache's TimeOut configuration option if you experience this problem often.`

Do these messages come from apache? (`/usr/sbin/httpd -v` => `Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)`)

How can we prevent apache from writing these messages, without loosing other, potentially more relevant messages?

Or how can we find out whether there is a real problem with the timeout setting?

Comment: It looks like that this logging is related to `Phusion Passenger`. Could you indicate whether you are using this software?

Comment: Apparently yes. It's installed, several `PassengerSomething` daemons are running, and our httpd.conf has: `<Directory /WebServer/apps/redmine> .. PassengerAppRoot /WebServer/redmine-private  </Directory>`

Comment: I will do some tests and let you know the outcome